# How to copy CLI command output to table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to copy CLI command output to table then save as data frame

```
 DD-NN-KK-OOLL(config)#display vlan 0000
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index  Type   State   F S P    VPI  VCI   FLOWTYPE FLOWPARA   LABEL
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 324  vdl    down    0 3 62   0    35    -        -            390
 452  vdl    down    0 3 62   -    -     -        -            390
 613  vdl    up      0 4 49   0    35    -        -            453
 614  vdl    up      0 4 49   -    -     -        -            453
 617  vdl    down    0 2 26   0    35    -        -            278
 618  vdl    down    0 2 26   -    -     -        -            278
 619  vdl    up      0 2 30   0    35    -        -            282
 620  vdl    up      0 2 30   -    -     -        -            282
 621  vdl    up      0 4 62   0    35    -        -            466
 622  vdl    up      0 4 62   -    -     -        -            466
 627  vdl    down    0 2 20   0    35    -        -            272
 628  vdl    down    0 2 20   -    -     -        -            272
```

---

The output I need

| Type | State | F | S | P | VPI | VCI | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vdl | down | 0 | 3 | 62 | 0 | 35 | 390 |
| vdl | down | 0 | 3 | 62 | - | - | 390 |
| vdl | up | 0 | 4 | 49 | 0 | 35 | 453 |
| vdl | up | 0 | 4 | 49 | - | - | 453 |
| vdl | down | 0 | 2 | 26 | 0 | 35 | 278 |
| vdl | down | 0 | 3 | 62 | - | - | 268 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: The link is useful to capture the output, I need also to save as a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
import subprocess
from io import StringIO
​
s = subprocess.check_output(["xclip", "-o"]).decode("UTF-8") #change the command here
​
df = (
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s\s*", skiprows=2, engine="python").loc[1:]
          #.drop(columns=["Index", "FLOWTYPE, "FLOWPARA"]) # is this optional ? If not, uncomment
)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

   Index Type State    F    S     P VPI VCI FLOWTYPE FLOWPARA  LABEL
1    324  vdl  down  0.0  3.0  62.0   0  35        -        -  390.0
2    452  vdl  down  0.0  3.0  62.0   -   -        -        -  390.0
3    613  vdl    up  0.0  4.0  49.0   0  35        -        -  453.0
4    614  vdl    up  0.0  4.0  49.0   -   -        -        -  453.0
5    617  vdl  down  0.0  2.0  26.0   0  35        -        -  278.0
..   ...  ...   ...  ...  ...   ...  ..  ..      ...      ...    ...
8    620  vdl    up  0.0  2.0  30.0   -   -        -        -  282.0
9    621  vdl    up  0.0  4.0  62.0   0  35        -        -  466.0
10   622  vdl    up  0.0  4.0  62.0   -   -        -        -  466.0
11   627  vdl  down  0.0  2.0  20.0   0  35        -        -  272.0
12   628  vdl  down  0.0  2.0  20.0   -   -        -        -  272.0

[12 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: **NB**: I used `xclip -o` in my [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) just to *simulate* your actual command.

Comment: Great thanks for you, can I make columns F,S,P LABEL integer not float

Comment: You're welcome and yes, you can do that by adding `.convert_dtypes()` as a last chain or use `df = df.convert_dtypes()`.

Comment: I have problem with the values of the LABEL column, after the row 12 , the column values appear NAN